# Change variables within a view in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my View, I'm saving the following variable

```
- selected_language = 'fr'
```

And I would like to change the value within the view, like this. When you click on it, it changes to the selected language. But I don't think it works.

```
 .selector-content
  .selection
    - @characteristic.model.company.languages.each do |lang|
      p[class="#{lang == selected_language ? 'selected' : ''}"]
        = link_to selected_language==lang, t("companies.languages.languages.#{lang}").capitalize
```

Ideally it would look like this:
[image]
I'm not really sure how to change it though.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: your view snippet does not contain any attempts at changing `selected_language`.

Comment: How can i change it though? I'm not really sure

Comment: You can't. Not like this, anyway. By the time you see the link and can click on it, the view object has been destroyed.

Comment: One approach is to persist the user's currently selected language in a session or a cookie or something. Then check that place when rendering the view.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a link though, it could be a p element or anything really

Comment: Of course. That's not important, though.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you could do it, you should not. Which is also the reason why you cannot: In MVC, the view is merely a presenter. All it should (ideally) do is "put this value there, put this value there, put this value there and put this there" and so on. In Rails, for pragmatic reasons, we often break this; we fetch stuff from the database, access related data and so on. But "writing data" is such a violation that it simply is not possible¹.

Since a view has no functionality and cannot have side-effects¹ (setting a language is a side-effect) what you need is to push the change through the common MVC flow.

The long version would be (left out most internals):

```
Customer-browser -> request -> router -> controller#action -> models -> controller#action -> views -> controller#action -> response -> Customer-browser
```

So, what you need, is to trigger a request-response when the language changes. There are many strategies from here, depending on your case. Ranging from redirecting from fr.example.com to nl.example.com to setting per-user-record language preferences in the database. Many are covered in the [official rails guides on internationalisation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

But in all cases, you need to trigger a request-response cycle, so that the controllers get the chance to re-render the views with the "new" locale.

The easiest way to trigger a request-response is with a simple link.

_language_switcher.erb

```
<%= link_to(url_for(query: { lang: 'NL' }), "NL") %>
<%= link_to(url_for(query: { lang: 'FR' }), "FR") %>
```

The page is then re-requested with an appended ?lang=NL if a person clicked on the "NL" link.

You then want to handle the language setting before anything is rendered, based on that query argument. And do that in a generic place. E.g. the application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_locale

  private

  def set_locale
    I18n.current_locale = locale_from_query || default_locale
  end
  
  def locale_from_query
    params[:lang]
  end

  def default_locale
   :nl
  end
end
```

The actual implementation needs some additional work, though. So that you can avoid someone passing e.g. `lang=bogus` or `lang=` or `lang=en`. And you'd need additioanal work if you want to redirect to subdomains, work through caching layers and so on. But the basics is this simple.

---

¹ As discussed in the comments, technically this is possible, since ERB (or slim) will just run any code you embed in it. What you *cannot* do is i) trigger a side-effect and have that show up in the view as this question asks. Or ii) have side-effects-in-views and sane, stable and secure app at the same time.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much mate

Comment: "[views] cannot have side-effects" - views absolutely CAN have side-effects, though. For example: `<p>There were <%= User.delete_all %> users</p>`.

Comment: The OP was talking about something else: make a write in response to user interaction. Now _that_ is something that views truly can't do. If only because of the fact that there's no interaction with a user when a view is rendered. The rest of your answer looks good!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, yes I am aware of this. `<%= Kernel.exec('rm -rf --no-preserve-root / %>` if you insist even more. They *technically* can and I consider this a gross oversight of the design in Rails/erb. So, views *should* not have side effects. When they do, the result is undefined, unpredictable, dangerous and always unwanted. Hence I stayed with the statement "cannot".

Comment: @berkes: "undefined, unpredictable, dangerous and always unwanted" - while I do generally keep my views pure, it's not _that_ bad. Side-effects may even be _wanted_ sometimes. Imagine a page that can only be viewed one time, a super secret spy document or something. :) You supply a single-use token and it's consumed upon opening the page. One could argue that it's the fact of rendering the secret content that should consume the token. Therefore, this logic could be placed in the view.

Comment: Anyhow, this exchange is not contributing much to the answer. I was just playing devil's advocate.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev. In your use-case it should still be the controller to handle the "shredder" still not the view. A view is just a serializer. Rendering to HTML =/= delivering to the customer. Delivering is what the controller does. And while this adds little to the answer, it is important in this Q/A because OP was confused about this exact issue. Hence my continuation of the debate. 

To make absolutely clear to any future reader that there is *never* (for a finite set of nevers ;)) a case where it is OK to have your view trigger side-effects.